# Bash error message: syntax error near unexpected token '|'

Tags: bash

I was creating a program that calculates the area of circle, but bash doesnt compile and execute due to error message in the title. Here is my code:

```
    elif [ $num -le 6 ] && [ $num -ge 4 ]
  then
      read -p "Enter radius: " radius
      let areaCirc=("scale=2;3.1416 * ($radius * $radius)"|bc)
      echo "Area of the circle is: " $areaCirc
```

and the error message is:
[syntax error near unexpected token '|'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ya96T.png)

can someone help me?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. For debugging help in the future, you need to make a [mre] with complete code, input (`$radius`), and expected output. In this case it's pretty clear from the context what you're trying to do, but it still took me a few minutes to figure it out.

Comment: I suggest to insert `echo`: `echo "scale=2;3.1416 * ($radius * $radius)"|bc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. To send a string to a command via stdin, use a [here-string](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Here-Strings) `command <<< string`, not a pipe.
2. [Command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) syntax is `$(...)`, not `(...)`.
3. Don't use `let` here. [Shell arithmetic](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Arithmetic.html) only supports integers.

```
areaCirc=$(bc <<< "scale=2;3.1416 * ($radius * $radius)")
```

Answer (score 0):

`let` provides arithmetic context, but we have an ambiguity here, because in a let expression, the vertical bar (`|`) means *bitwise or*, but in the shell it has also the meaning of a pipe operator. Look at the following examples:

```
let bc=4
let a=(4+bc)   # Sets a to 8
let b=("5+bc") # Sets b to 9

let c=("(2+4)|bc")
```

This is syntactically correct and sets c to 6 (because 2+4 equals 6, and the bitwise *or*  of 6 and 4 equals 6).

However if we decided to quote only part of the argument, i.e.

```
let c=("(2+4)"|bc)
```

or don't quote at all, i.e.

```
let c=((2+4)|bc)
```

we get a syntax error. The reason is that the shell, when parsing a command, first separates it into the different commands, which then are strung together. The pipe is such an operator, and the shell thinks that you want to do a `let areaCirc=("scale=2;3.1416 * ($radius * $radius)"` and pipe the result into `bc`. As you can see, the `let` statement is uncomplete; hence the syntax error.

Aside from this, even if you would fix it, your using of `let` would not work, because you are using a fractional number (`3.1416`), and `let` can do only integer arithmetic. As a workaround, either you do the whole calculation using `bc`, or some other language (`awk`, `perl`,...), or, if this is an option, you switch from bash to zsh, where you can do floating point arithmetic in the shell.